# OGROGR and SQL: unexpected reserved keyword error?

Tags: sql, ogr2ogr, natural-earth

As I do the following query on naturalearth [places.shp](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_populated_places.zip) :

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -sql "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places WHERE ADM0NAME = 'India' ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC LIMIT 1,30" places.tmp.geo.json ne_10m_populated_places.shp
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1: SQL Expression Parsing Error: syntax error, unexpected 
reserved keyword, expecting end of string. Occured around :
DM0NAME = 'India' ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC LIMIT 1,30
                                        ^
```

**How could I pass over it ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default OGR SQL engine does not support LIMIT. Try switching to the SQLite dialect, which is done by adding the argument

```
-dialect SQLITE
```

ie.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -sql "SELECT * FROM ne_10m_populated_places WHERE ADM0NAME = 'India' ORDER BY POP_MAX DESC LIMIT 1,30" -dialect SQLITE places.tmp.geo.json ne_10m_populated_places.shp
```

Comment: Limit with this syntax means the same than LIMIT 30 OFFSET 1 so it selects biggest cities beginning from the second biggiest. Is that the meaning?